# Angular 6 can't disable enable input with local reference

Tags: angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using reactive form in my angular application.

```
measurement: new FormControl(true),
volume: new FormControl(0)
```

And in my html i'm using like

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName='measurement' #measurement>Volume
<input formControlName='volume' type="number" class="form-control input-md" [attr.disabled]="!measurement.checked">
```

When ever I check 'Volume' check box it should enable 'volume' control. But it is not switching between enable and disable. But if I console 'measurement.checked' it is show true or false. How can I do enable or disable via local reference? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled cannot be Set Dynamically like your approach for more info 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271 . But you can enable or disable via function in onchange like control.enable() , control.disable()

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through typescript function..

Change the below line in your code,

```
<input formControlName='volume' type="number" class="form-control input-md" [attr.disabled]="!measurement.checked">
```

to

```
<input formControlName='volume' type="number" class="form-control input-md" [attr.disabled]="disableVolume()">
```

and in your ts file, add the function `disableVolume()`,

```
  disableVolume() {
    if(this.form.get('measurement').value === true) {
      this.form.get('volume').enable();
    } else {
      this.form.get('volume').disable();
    }
  }
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-cc27c3